# Handling views with duplicate function names

Tags: flask

Is there any way, in Flask, to handle the issue of duplicate function names for views across files?  Just to be clear, I'm talking about the name of the function, not the route defined for the function.  So imagine in `file1.py` I've got:

```
@app.route('/some/unique/route')
def duplicateFunctionName():
   ...python code...
```

And then in `file2.py` I've got:

```
@app.route('/another/unique/route/name')
def duplicateFunctionName():
   ...python code...
```

And then in `main.py` I import these view functions:

```
import file1
import file2

<<code to run the flask server>>
```

The problem is that in large projects it's really hard to keep the function names unique.  At some point you're bound to have two functions called `def saveData()` or whatever, and it's really hard to debug those issues.  Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Unless you're using `from fileN import *` the two functions will remain in their own namespaces as `file1.duplicateFunctionName` and `file2.duplicateFunctionName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Use the `endpoint` keyword argument to `.route`:

   ```
   @app.route('/some/unique/route', endpoint="unique_name_1")
   def duplicateFunctionName():
       pass

   @app.route('/another/unique/route', endpoint="unique_name_2")
   def duplicateFunctionName():
       pass
   ```

   This will ensure that all of your functions are addressable by `url_for`, etc.  However, you will need to ensure that all of your *endpoint* names are unique, so it's not perfect.
2. Use `Blueprint`'s to split up your routes into smaller self-contained packages:

   ```
    bp1 = Blueprint("module_one", __name__)

    @bp1.route("/some/unique/route")
    def duplicateFunctionName():
        pass

    bp2 = Blueprint("module_two", __name__)

    @bp2.route("/another/unique/route")
    def duplicateFunctionName():
        pass
   ```

   The advantage here is that the endpoint name is prefixed with the name of the blueprint, which means that instead of having two endpoints with the conflicting name `duplicateFunctionName` you now have two endpoints with the names `module_one.duplicateFunctionName` and `module_two.duplicateFunctionName`.